# I got an error using 'char' in matlab

Tags: matlab, char

I need some help guys. Im new to matlab and i really dont know how to solve this problem. It gives me this error " Error using char
Cell elements must be character arrays. " I need to simulate a contest and input 10 participants, and for each one the number of likes and comments. And if the number of likes is 0 he/ she its excluded from this contest.

Error in data(line 40)
        fprintf('The third winner is %s \n',char(cv))

```
n=input('Number of people ');
cs=zeros(1,n);
id1=cell(1,n);
for i=1:n
    id=input('Name','s');
    l=input('Number of likes is ');
    c=input('Numarul  of comments is');
    if (l==1)
        id1{i}=id;
        cs(i)=c;
    end
end
ord=0;
while(ord~=1)
    ord=1;
    for i=1:n-1
        if (cs(i)<cs(i+1))
            ord=0;
            aux=cs(i);
            cs(i)=cs(i+1);
            cs(i+1)=aux;
            aux1=id1{i};
            id1{i}=id1{i+1};
            id1{i+1}=aux1;
        end
    end
end
ct=id1{randi(numel(id1))};
fprintf('the winner is %s \n',ct)
csn='roata';
cv='salam';
cpl='ciorba';
for i=1:4
    if (((strcmp(id1(i),ct))==0) && (strcmp(csn,'roata')))
        csn=id1(i);
        fprintf('The second winner is %s \n',char(csn))
    end
    if (((strcmp(id1(i),ct))==0) && ((strcmp(id1(i),csn))==0) && (strcmp(cv,'salam')))
        cv=id1(i);
        fprintf('The third winner is %s \n',char(cv))
    end
    if (((strcmp(id1(i),ct))==0) && ((strcmp(id1(i),csn))==0) && ((strcmp(id1(i),cpl))==0) && (strcmp(cv,'ciorba')))
        cv=id1(i);
        fprintf('the third winner is %s \n',char(cpl))
    end
end
```

Comment: Please provide the inputs needed for this to happen

Comment: PROTIP: Indent your MATLAB code by `CTRL+A` `CTRL+I` on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has countless of cases where it would error, as you don't take all the possibilities of inputs into account.

I managed to get your error by giving `input('Number of likes is ');` a value other than 1. Then, your if condition never happens, thus `id1` doesn't get filled. If that `id1` is then accessed later in `fprintf('The third winner is %s \n',char(id(i)))`, you get an error, as `id(i)` is an empty `{0x0}` cell, that can not be converted to char.

Comment: I need to simulate a contest and input 10 participants, and for each one the number of likes and comments. And if the number of likes is 0 he/ she its excluded from this contest. the winner is chosen randomly than the other 3 winners are chosen by depending on the number of comments ( who has the most comments its on the second place, the next one on the third and the next one on the last )

Comment: @MariaxJoe yes, very well. Surely I am not going to code it for you! I understood its some kind of game. I pointed out your error, now its your job to fix it and do your exercise ;)

Comment: i know :D i dont want that thing to happen, i am so grateful you helped me. thanks a lot!

Comment: @MariaxJoe consider accepting the answer as valid then ;)